Is there a QRCode in Delphi 11 VCL?
I was previously using Delphi 7 and it had the normal codebar and QRcode, when I used Delphi 11 VCL and wanted to print a report using FastReport, I found only the normal codebar, I could not find the QRCode in the obCatBarcode field inside the report.
Do you have any idea how I can display QRCode in a report, without using external libraries?

Delphi has never had a QRcode component of its own. If you had one in Delphi 7, it must have been a 3rd party component that you installed separately.  FastReport is a 3rd party component suite. Does this article on FastReport's site help? How to generate QR code in FastReport VCL with Delphi/Lazarus code

@RemyLebeau The problem is that the QRCode appeared in Delphi7, but it did not appear in Delphi11. Other normal types appeared for me. Like the picture in the article [link] (https://fastreportsimages.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/08.22/QRCode_VCL_1.png)

Then I suggest you contact FastReport directly to figure out why the QRCode option is not appearing for you and how to enable it.

@RemyLebeau Well dude, I really appreciate your help, and I appreciate your time, thanks again.

FastReports did not exist when Delphi 7 was the current version, which means it did not appear in Delphi 7. The reporting option that shipped with Delphi 7 was QuickReports. As @Remy said, it had to have been something added by a 3rd party product. Contact FastReports to discuss why it isn't there any longer or where it was moved to instead.

Fastreport 4.0 can be installed on D7, but Quickreport QRCode  add-on equivalent is a TfrxQRCodeObject you have to drop on your Tfrxreport containing form.
Now, using a Fastreport registered version, I don't remember if Embarcadero FastReport version have this TfrxQRCodeObject component
